# Is there a way of "bitwise" decrypting a corrupt Bitlocker encrypted raw HDD-image

Tags: encryption, bitlocker

I'm facing a situation, where I'd like to decrypt a "corrupted" Bitlocker protected drive (Windows 10 Partition) by using the known 48-digit recovery key. Corrupt means, I executed a restore (Windows internal restore of a System Image) procedure that got stuck, leaving me with an, as it seems, unusable Bitlocker header, so that the Microsoft tools repair-bde or manage-bde -status don't recognize the drive as a Bitlocker-protected one.*

Does anybody know how to decrypt the encrypted raw disk image by using the recovery key, to get another (but decrypted) raw disk image (with which I could perform further data restore steps)?

---

* As this is not directly relevant to the question (but the topic may occur) I'm going to describe my situation for those interested in more detailed here:
Notebook without TPM. Two fixed drives, one with Windows 10, Bitlocker protected, and a secondary (data) drive, Bitlocker protected as well. The second one was set-up for auto-unlock when booting up the OS. System Image (Windows internal Back up and restore function) existent on the Second drive, which I tried to restore two the primary drive. That restore process crashed, leaving me with an unusable system. Three obvious mistakes (yep, I learned my lesson...): 1. I don't have another backup on an independent (external) drive, 2. I didn't create an raw-image of the intact system drive before using the fragile Windows restore, 3. I only have the user-defined *password* for this second drive and not the recovery key (48-digit or .bek file). Unfortunately the password by itself takes me nowhere without the OS that I just killed, respectively switching to auto-unlock seems to change the "keychain", so at the moment accessing the backup of the first drive is impossible.

The last two approaches I had in mind are to see what I can rescue from the primary drive, and to see, whether I can extract the stored auto-unlock key (further reading on this [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d691044a-1888-47dd-bec5-105066ebe41a/bitlocker-autounlock-restore-data-without-recovery-key?forum=win10itprosecurity#f6477b3c-986a-4d59-9175-434b066c7e59)), to unlock the secondary drive, with the intact system image on it.

Answer (score 0):

Update on this: it seems that the Microsoft restore process first wipes the drive, and then restores the image *unencrypted* (at least to the point where it crashed) probably before encrypting it again.
Therefore I am now able to restore the relevant User Data on the primary OS drive with conventional recovery tools.

As I wrote beforehand the computer has a fixed second Bitlocker encrypted drive, which was set to auto-unlock before the faulty Windows restore process.

With the recovery of the primary drive I was able to get the *Data* Key stored in the registry at

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FVEAutoUnlock\

which starts with 70 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 14 aa 47 e0 89 4e 0e 4c ...

I've [read](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dubaisec/2018/07/11/bitlocker-auto-unlock/) that it is a DPAPI encrypted key, which should be decryptable with [DataProtectionDecryptor](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dpapi_data_decryptor.html), but it doesnt start with the standard DPAPI sequence 01 00 00 00 D0 8C 9D ... . So at the moment I don't know **which information(keys) to use and where they come from to transform this key to the valid Bitlocker recovery key?**